# Using dynamic allocation to create an array and insert elements into it

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, allocation

I want to make a library management system as an assignment

```
class student
{
          char ID_number[30];
          char Student_name[30];
      public:
          void create_student()
          {
                    cout<<"\nEnter The ID Number ";
                    cin>>ID_number;
                    cout<<"\n\nEnter The Name of The Student: ";
                    cin>>Student_name;

                    cout<<"\n\nStudent Created Successfully"<<endl;
          }
          void show_student()
          {
                    cout<<"\nID Number: "<<ID_number;
                    cout<<"\nStudent Name: ";
                    cin.getline(Student_name,30);


          }
```

How would i go about using dynamic allocation to make every new entry go into an array and use pointers to show a certain student?

I am really bad at this particular part, thanks in advance!

Comment: You may use `std::vector<student>`.

Comment: Well sadly for this assignment i can only use dynamic allocation

I think i can do it but not without listing a specific array size

Comment: `vector` provide dynamic allocation. You don't need to specify the size of it

Comment: So write your own `vector`.

Comment: Sorry i haven't been very clear, i need to use new[] and delete[] not vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by dynamic you mean you want to create "a few" stduent records, but aren't sure how many you don't need to worry about new or delete. Just use a vector.

```
std::vector<student> students;
while(!bored)
{
    student latest;
    latest.creat_student(); // this looks a bit odd, perhaps it should be a free function...
    vector.push_back(latest);
    //TODO - see if I am bored yet
}
```

Now we have students. You said you wanted to use pointers to display them. Or rather a certain student. You haven't described how you will choose a "certain student", so let's show them all first

```
for (auto item : students)
{
    item.show_student();
}
```

Disappointingly, your `show_student` method isn't declared const, which you should consider.

To index to a particular student, you could use `students[17]`. Or which ever index you want. You might be able to use std algorithms to [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) students with particular properies, if you provide a way to get the properties (and of course consider using `std::string` instead of `char *`)

---

If you really want to use a raw array of `student`, then something like this works, but you will get into reallocs etc if 5 or whatever you choose isn't enough. Which is a compelling reason for choosing a `std::vector`.

```
student * them = new student[5];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    student latest;
    latest.create_student();
    them[i] = latest;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    them[i].show_student();
}
delete[] them;
```

Comment: Okay so with new and delete i have to declare the size of my array every time?

Comment: Exactly - just added an edit. Vector deals with this for you, and reallocates when it needs to. If you use a raw array you need to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are coding in C++, and not in C, I would suggest using a string *class*, like `std::string`, instead of raw `char` arrays, e.g.:

```
std::string student_name;
```

If you want to store a list of students in memory, I'd suggest using the `std::vector` container, e.g.:

```
std::vector<Student> students;
```

You can use the `vector::push_back` method to add new students to the container.

---

**EDIT** If you want to use `new[]` and `delete[]` as a learning exercise, you may allocate a big array of students, and then use an integer index inside the array, pointing to the first free slot for inserting new students.
E.g.:

```
int capacity = 100;
Student* students = new Student[capacity];

int student_count = 0;
```

To add a new student, you copy it in the array index given by `student_count`, and then you increment this variable by one, pointing to the next free slot in the pre-allocated array.

You must pay attention to *not* overflow the capacity of the array. Once the pre-allocated array is full, if you want to add a new student you need to allocate a new array with bigger capacity. You can use a 2x or 1.5x scale factor to calculate the new capacity.

Dont't forget to release the memory previously allocated with `delete[]`.

If you do that, you are basically kind of implementing `std::vector` from scratch (even if this standard container has additional advanced features, like move semantics, etc.).

Comment: But string doesn't let it read more than on word after the space no? I want it to read a full line of characters i.e "john doe", if i use string and cin>>student_name; it'll just get "john" and ignore the rest

And i can only use dynamic allocation in this assignment, actually this is the whole point of the assignment sadly.

Edit: to be clear i need to use new[] and delete[] no vectors

Comment: @00qq00: Good question. Use `getline(cin, student_name);`.

Comment: Thanks this works!, any idea how to use new[] delete[] instead of vectors?

Comment: Thanks, i'll go ahead and try

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<student>` or `std::vector<student*>` if you want a `pointer`.

Adding a new student :

```
Student* newStudent = new Student(name);

vector.append(newStudent);
```

Reading a student called **"Victor"** and then deleting it:

```
Student* victor;
for(int i = 0; i<vector.size();i++) {
    if(vector.at(i)->getName() == "Victor") {
        victor = vector.at(i);
        break;
    }
 }
//Then you can delete it
delete(victor);
```

[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: I can only use new[] and delete[] so any ideas how and where to insert them?

Comment: I am not sure of what do you mean with new and delete.

Comment: public:  
   void * operator new[] (size_t)  
   {  
      return 0;  
   }  
   void   operator delete[] (void*)  
   {  
   }  
};  
  
int main()   
{  
   MyClass *pMyClass = new MyClass[5];  
   delete [] pMyClass;  
}


I need to use something like this

Comment: That would work if you insist on using a c-style array, sorta by why define your own?

Comment: Is it a student exercice ? If it is @Mr.C64 is better than mine.